# PL/SQL - Iterating over cursor and assigning value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This may be a basic question, but I'm relatively new to PL/SQL and I'm stuck.

Let's say I have a cursor, for example:

```
cursor pr_cur(pr_id varchar2) 
is
  select priority
  from some_table
  where id = pr_id;
```

The priority column can have only 3 possible values:
'Low', 'High', 'Very high'

I want to iterate through the cursor and assign the highest priority found to a variable: max_pr.

```
for pr_rec in pr_cur(some_value)
loop
  max_pr := pr_rec.priority;
  exit when pr_rec.priority = 'Very high';
end loop;
```

I hope this is not a duplicate question.
How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** need a Cursor and **loops** for this with unwanted `if else`. You can use a single sql query to get the max priority using  appropriate `ORDER BY` with `row_number` or `FETCH FIRST`

In *Oracle 11g*

```
SELECT
    priority
INTO max_pr
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    CASE priority
                        WHEN 'Very high'   THEN 1
                        WHEN 'High'        THEN 2
                        WHEN 'Low'         THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
                    END
            ) AS rn
        FROM
            some_table t
    )
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

*Oracle 12c* and above

```
SELECT
    priority
INTO max_pr
FROM
    some_table t
ORDER BY
    CASE priority
        WHEN 'Very high'   THEN 1
        WHEN 'High'        THEN 2
        WHEN 'Low'         THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this in your PL/SQL:

```
for pr_rec in pr_cur(some_value)
loop

    CASE pr_rec.priority
        WHEN 'Very high' THEN
            max_pr := pr_rec.priority
        WHEN 'High' THEN
            IF max_pr IS NULL or max_pr = 'Low' THEN
                max_pr := pr_rec.priority
            END IF;
        WHEN 'Low' THEN
            IF max_pr IS NULL THEN
                max_pr := pr_rec.priority
            END IF;
    END CASE;

    exit when max_pr = 'Very high';

end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help--

```
for pr_rec in (select priority
              from some_table
              where id = pr_id)
loop
    max_pr := pr_rec.priority;
    if max_pr= 'Very high' then
        exit;
    end if;
end loop;
```